# Changing the div structure to new div structure using css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have very large number if div that representing the student name

```
<div class="student" style="color: black;">Student 1 </div>
<div class="student" style="color: blue;">Student 2</div>
<div class="student" style="color: red;">Student 3 </div>
       etc
```

Now I need to replace the div of each student into following structure

```
<div class="student-parent">
   <div class="student" style="color: {color of student}"> </div>
   <br>
   <div class="student-text"> {name of student} </div>
</div>
```

For example : for student 1 i need to replace this to

```
<div class="student-parent">
   <div class="student" style="color:black"> </div>
   <br>
   <div class="student-text"> Student 1 </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this using css or jQuery . Since there are more than 1000 student div i cannot rewrite all div structure to new div structure Please help .

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: show your attempt in code and detail where you are experiencing a problem. This is not a free coding site, it's intended for solving specific problems with existing code. You are expected to do some research and show some effort first :-)

Comment: Mate, had a tough time cleaning your post! `:P`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery... But definitely you need to structure your server side code that generates, because, the browser might cry for such a huge DOM manipulation.

But this is the way:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".student").each(function () {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="student-parent" />')
      .after('<div class="student-text">' + $(this).text() + '</div>')
      .after('<br />')
      .text("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="student" style="color: black;">Student 1 </div>
<div class="student" style="color: blue;">Student 2</div>
<div class="student" style="color: red;">Student 3 </div>
```

**Few Pointers** moving ahead:

- Structure should be made from the Server Side or generating code.
- Use pagination and don't load huge data on the client side at a single time.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery and Mustache template it would look something easy as this:

```js
var tpl = '<div class="student-parent">'+
            '<div class="student" style="color: {{color}}"> </div>'+
            '<br>'+
            '<div class="student-text">{{name}}</div>'+
            '<br>'+
          '</div>';

$( ".student" ).each(function( index ) {
  
  var data = {
      color: $(this).css("color"),
      name: $(this).text()
  };
  var html = Mustache.to_html(tpl, data);
  $(this).replaceWith(html);  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>

<div class="student" style="color: black;">Student 1 </div>
<div class="student" style="color: blue;">Student 2</div>
<div class="student" style="color: red;">Student 3 </div>
```

Comment: Now why do you need Mustache! That's a crazy overkill. LoL. But indeed another way! `:)`

Comment: @praveen I hope that this way the template is easier to understand and better for future edits. But yes, your script works as well and does the job.